# Setting Http response data as a varible in Mule4

Tags: anypoint-studio, mule4

I am trying to set http response values in variable. Below is response from http request

```
{
"kind": "drive#file",
"id": "1MxumGPQD9dH161BQJCoJ_",
"name": "2020_August",
"mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
}
```

How can i set only the id field in a variable after getting above reponse.

Am trying this logic in trans form message

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "id":payload.id
}
```

But giving me error

Comment: What is the error? Transformation looks good.

Comment: Below is the error am getting

Comment: "You called the function 'Value Selector' with these arguments: 
  1: Binary ("ewogImtpbmQiOiAiZHJpdmUjZmlsZSIsCiAiaWQiOiAiMWlkUlUxcTBKanhCZ1QzeS1TT082d3pB...)
  2: Name ("id")

But it expects one of these combinations:
  (Array, Name)
  (Array, String)
  (Date, Name)
  (DateTime, Name)
  (LocalDateTime, Name)
  (LocalTime, Name)
  (Object, Name)
  (Object, String)
  (Period, Name)
  (Time, Name)

5|     "id":payload.id
            ^^^^^^^^^^
Trace:
  at main (line: 5, column: 10)" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
    "id":payload.id
}"

Comment: It seems that the response is being interpreted as a binary instead of a JSON. You should also add the XML of the flow, in text please. Just the transformation script alone is not enough to understand the problem. Also what is the HTTP response content-type, other headers and payload. You can print all with HTTP wire logging https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-Enable-HTTP-Wire-Logging

Comment: Http content type is application/json

Comment: Add one more transformation in frontof your to be sure that payload is json. outoput application/json --- payload.

Answer (score 0):

The content that's returned from your HttpRequest call is binary.

Try this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
id: read(payload, "application/json").'id'
```

which should return what you're looking for:

```
{
  "id": "1MxumGPQD9dH161BQJCoJ_"
}
```

If you are capturing that into a local variable, define the same using a set-variable, like this:

```
<set-variable value="#[read(payload, &quot;application/json&quot;).'id']" doc:name="id" variableName="id"/>
```